# what is the integer that return by getInt(string key) in android.os.Bundle?

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

i read document about getInt() method :

> public int getInt (String key)
>
> Returns the value associated with the given key, or 0 if no mapping of
>   the desired type exists for the given key.
>
> Parameters:
>
> key    a string
>
> return:
>
> an int value

but i can't get it that what it exactly return.

the ID of `key` that is in R.java or no something else???

Comment: the value of the key for example {"data":1}, getInt("data")  = 1

Comment: what it returns depends on the parameter you send (as the description explains).
If you have a set {{"one", 1},{"two",2}} "one" will return 1, "two" will return 2, and "three" will return 0

Comment: @Proxytype the parameter is a string, and what about { key = "possition" ; } ???

Comment: @hamid_c: the "data" in his example is a String. if the key = "possition", in Proxytype's example it would return 0, since he has no element with that key in his set.

Comment: i believed it will throw exception or zero..

Comment: Exception of zero? what do you mean by that? it will return 0 (not throw an Exception) because there is no element with key "possition". and, the method is designed to return "0 if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns whatever you've put in that bundle with the same key.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("KEY", 1);
int value = bundle.getInt("KEY"); // returns 1
```

It's simply a map/dictionary datatype where you map a string value with something else. If you have other datatypes, you should use the appropriate put/get-methods for that datatype.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing better that with an example

Suppose you have two activities: Activity1 and Activity2 and you want to pass data beetwen then:

**Activity1**

```
private static final String MY_KEY = "My Key"
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putInt(MY_KEY, 112233);

intent.putExtras(b);

startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity 2**

```
private static final String MY_KEY = "My Key"
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

int value = b.getInt(MY_KEY , 0);

//value now have the value 112233
```

What means "*Returns the value associated with the given key, or 0 if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.*" in this example?

Using Bundle you're sending the value **112233** from Activity 1 to Activity 2 using the key "MY_KEY". So, "MY_KEY" is associated with 112233.

As you can see there is a second parameter “0”.

> It is the default value. In situation when Bundle doesn’t contains
>   data you will receive “0” (default value).